# Is it possible to disable/enable primary keys in mySQL Like we do in oracle SQL?

Tags: mysql, oracle11g

**Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'**

How to insert the duplicate values into the table of **mySQL** by disabling\enabling  the primary keys like we perform in oracle SQL

**Examples:**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
DISABLE CONSTRAINT constraint_name;

ALTER TABLE table_name
ENABLE CONSTRAINT constraint_name;
```

Comment: If the column has duplicates then, by definition, it can't be a primary key.  But moreover, why would you want to do this?

Comment: I just want to check whether it is possible or not. Because in sql-plus(oracle) we can add duplicate values by disabling the existing primary key for a table.

Comment: the first answer is correct but i obviously would advise adding duplicate values to a primary key otherwise it defeats the point of a primary key

Comment: Yes,That is what i'm thinking to do because in Oracle it is possible but in mySQL ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

`DISABLE KEYS` or

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

Comment: DISABLE KEYS disables updating on nonunique indexes only, and doesn't work for innodb. If you try it with an innodb table you'll get a warning "Note  | 1031 | Table storage engine for 'tablename' doesn't have this option".